# Tapestry, request processing from another application

Tags: httpclient, tapestry

i'have two web appli, tapestry appli and a simple web appli(servelt). in tapestry appli , i have  a form, and when it'll be sent, i call a httpClient for sending some informations to author appli using apache's httpClient. like this

```
    void onSubmitFromForm() {

    try {

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/appli2/recep");
        post.setHeader("referer", "http://localhost:9090/app1/start");

        List<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

        param.add(new BasicNameValuePair("_data", getData());

        post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                    response ?????
            } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

And in my servelt recep of the simple web appli(2) i do the same like below

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(request.getHeader("referer"));

        post.setHeader("p",getP());

        client.execute(post);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

So, my recep  reviev data from  my form  but it'cannot response it,  i'would  that tapersty appli could recieve  the param  'P' from the simple web appli ? 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm correct you want your tapestry application to POST some form data received from a form submit within Tapestry to a servlet running on another application.

If this is what you want then what is missing is the haneling of the request and constructing a response in your servlet. Because both your tapestry page and your servlet are POST'ing meaning neither constructs a response for your HttpClient to deal with.

In your servlet you could:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, 
     HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException
  {
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.println(getP());
    out.close();
  }
```

And deal with the response in your tapesty form handler.